# Elementor / Videos disapear

Tags: wordpress, video, elementor

I'm Pascal from france.
I developed a WP site with the plugin elementor one year ago.
Everything was fine until, a week ago, my videos disappeared.
Example here : https://maelyneevolution.com/index.php/test2/

What happened ? What changed ? The plugin ? Wordpress (I tried to upgrade it. No changes) ?
Sometimes, we can hear the sound of the video, but no image. Nothing, not even a black square.
Sometimes the video appears and...pfft ! Dissapears.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to put videos is by 1st uploading them on youtube then you can show that video on your website using embed or by elementor widget

Your server might be slow or you may have used some cache plugin or something that caused the issue. But embedding youtube video will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it, I embedded the youtube link. It didn't work either.

Comment: https://maelyneevolution.com/index.php/test2/